# java subtype and subclass and true subtype

Tags: java, inheritance

I have read a lot of explanations about the java sub-typing and the true sub-typing and
the subclass but every time I get more confused, please I need a perfect explanation to all the mentioned above, I am right at following statements?

1. every class that inherits from another class is a subclass
2. some class is a java sub-class to another class if it has the same methods
3. true sub-typing is when we can replace a reference between two classes

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**every class the inherits from another class is a subclass**

I will correct this to

> "every class that extends another class is a subclass"

and FYI every class in java extends `java.lang.Object` class by default except `Object` class itself.

**some class is a java sub-class to another class if it has the same methods**

This is not true. consider following example

```
class A {
   public void someMethod(){
      // method code
   }
}

class B {
   public void someMethod(){
      // method code
   }
}
```

Both are independent class, `B` is not subclass of `A` or `A` is not subclass of `B`.

**true sub-typing is when we can replace a reference between two classes**

**EDIT :**

```
class A {
   public void someMethod(){
      // method code
   }
}

class B extends A{
   public void someMethod(){
      // method code
   }
}
```

You can create object of class `B` which is subclass of `A` as

```
A objB = new B();
```

This concept is [Runtime Polymorphism](http://java.dzone.com/articles/runtime-polymorphism-java). and you can check an article [Inheritance in Java](http://java8.in/unit-2-prog-6-inheritance-in-java/) on that.

Comment: thanks, but still what is the difference between java subtype and true subtype moreover if class A extends B then here every B ISA A then I can replace between them!

Answer (score 0):

Only the first of these statements is true.

**#2:** If a class is the sub-class of another class, it will have the same methods (The reverse of this statement is not necessarily true). Consider this example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public void sayHello () 
    { 
         System.out.println ("Hello!");
    };
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public void sayHello () 
    { 
         System.out.println ("Woof! I'm a dog.");
    };
}

public class WebApplication
{
    public void sayHello () 
    { 
         System.out.println ("Welcome!");
    };
}
```

Both `WebApplication` and `Dog` have a similar `sayHello` method, but only `Dog` is a sub-class of `Animal`.

**#3:** I don't know what you mean by "replace a reference". If `Dog` is a sub-class of `Animal`, you can assign a `Dog` object to an `Animal` reference, but not vice versa.

Comment: can you explain I got an exam and I am totally lost bcause each time I understand some thing different!!